# Handling state changes doesn't seem to wait for state resolve

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following code to handle the access to certain states based on authentication. For example, if the user is logged in, they shouldn't be able to get to /login or /signup. Also, if they are not logged in they should not be able to access /admin. The problem I am having is related to a previous question (see: [Waiting for $http before running angular spa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708624/waiting-for-http-before-running-angular-spa)).  Upon fixing that issue, the resolve does not happen before the $stateChangeStart event is triggered. This causes a user who is logged in on the /admin page who refreshes the browser to get bumped to the /login page, even though they are logged in. I am hoping there is a way for this to wait as well, or maybe I need to adjust my resolve on my state.

Handle state changes in run():

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (toState.access && toState.access.noauth && AuthenticationService.isLogged()) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.transitionTo('app.admin.dashboard');
    }
    if (toState.access && toState.access.auth && !AuthenticationService.isLogged()) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.transitionTo('app.login');
    }
});
```

Resolve for authentication verification:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/',
        views: {
            root: {
                templateUrl: 'tpl/index.html'
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            User: ['$window', '$q', 'AuthenticationService', 'UserService' , function($window, $q, AuthenticationService, UserService) {
                if ($window.sessionStorage.token && !AuthenticationService.isLogged()) {
                    var d = $q.defer();
                    UserService.verify().success(function (data) {
                        AuthenticationService.setLogged(true);
                        d.resolve();
                    }).error(function () {
                        delete $window.sessionStorage.token;
                        d.resolve();
                    });
                    return d.promise;
                }
            }]
        }
    });
```